# xkb: how can `modifier_map` be completely replaced

Tags: xkb, setxkbmap

When defining a custom keyboard layout with xkb, how can I completely override a modifier?  E.g. when I have

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"      };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"      };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)"     };
    xkb_symbols   {
        include "pc+us"
        override modifier_map Mod4 { <LALT>, <RALT> };
    };
};
```

I expect that Mod4 is only generated for the two "Alt" keys.  But

```
xkbcomp test :0 && xkbcomp :0 generated
grep Mod4 generated
```

shows that old mappings (from pc105) are still applied

```
    modifier_map Mod4 { <LALT> };
    modifier_map Mod4 { <RALT> };
    modifier_map Mod4 { <LWIN> };
    modifier_map Mod4 { <RWIN> };
    modifier_map Mod4 { <SUPR> };
    modifier_map Mod4 { <HYPR> };
```